# Implement a column renderer for Vaadin 8 Grid

Tags: datagrid, vaadin, renderer, vaadin8

The [Vaadin Framework](https://vaadin.com/framework) guide has a [page describing how to use Column Renderers](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.renderer) in a [Vaadin Grid](https://vaadin.com/grid). And [this page describes implementing renderers](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/clientsidewidgets/clientsidewidgets-grid.html#clientsidewidgets.grid.renderers), but all too briefly.

I want to implement a `InstantRenderer` to complement the partial set of java.time renderers added in Vaadin 8.1. Renderers were added for `LocalDate` & `LocalDateTime` but not for `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime`. For my `Instant` renderer I am currently simply applying the current default time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime` on which I call the `toString` method. More could be done, but this is just to get started.

So my code should be very similar to the provided `LocalDateTimeRenderer`. I am trying to follow that code as an guide.

In searching the Vaadin source code and reading the doc, it seems I need three pieces of source code:

- `InstantRenderer` ( similar to [`LocalDateTimeRenderer`](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/ui/renderers/LocalDateTimeRenderer.java) )
- `InstantRendererConnector` ( similar to [`LocalDateTimeRendererConnector`](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/client/src/main/java/com/vaadin/client/connectors/grid/LocalDateTimeRendererConnector.java) )
- `InstantRendererState` ( similar to [`LocalDateTimeRendererState`](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/shared/src/main/java/com/vaadin/shared/ui/grid/renderers/LocalDateTimeRendererState.java) )

I have done this, and it all compiles. But my table fails to render, all I get is a white empty box on the page. No errors appear on the console or logs. If I remove my use of my `InstantRenderer`, and fall back to letting my `Instant` objects be rendered by the default of their own `toString` methods, all is well and the table appears as expected. So I know my custom renderer is at fault.

I am a newbie when it comes to "server-side" vs "client-side" Vaadin.

➠ Is there some kind of packaging I need to perform? Currently I have my three classes in my Vaadin project alongside the `MyUI` source file.

➠ Am I missing some other piece?

I instantiate my renderer by calling the no-arg constructor:

```
this.entriesGrid
    .addColumn( Entry::getStart )
    .setCaption( "Start" )
    .setRenderer( new InstantRenderer(  ) )
;
```

Here are my three files listed above, taken almost entirely from the Vaadin source code.

### `InstantRenderer`

```
/*
 * By Basil Bourque. Taken almost entirely from source code published by Vaadin Ltd.
 *
 * --------
 *
 * Copyright 2000-2016 Vaadin Ltd.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 * use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
 * the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */

package com.basil.timepiece;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;

import java.util.Locale;

import elemental.json.JsonValue;

/**
 * A renderer for presenting {@code Instant} objects.
 *
 * @author Vaadin Ltd
 * @since 8.1
 */
public class InstantRenderer
        extends com.vaadin.ui.renderers.AbstractRenderer< Object, Instant >
{
    private DateTimeFormatter formatter;
    private boolean getLocaleFromGrid;

    private ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault(); // Basil Bourque.

    /**
     * Creates a new InstantRenderer.
     * <p>
     * The renderer is configured to render with the grid's locale it is
     * attached to, with the format style being {@code FormatStyle.LONG} for the
     * date and {@code FormatStyle.SHORT} for time, with an empty string as its
     * null representation.
     *
     * @see <a href=
     * "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html#LONG">
     * FormatStyle.LONG</a>
     * @see <a href=
     * "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html#SHORT">
     * FormatStyle.SHORT</a>
     */
    public InstantRenderer ()
    {
        this( DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.LONG , FormatStyle.SHORT ) , "" );
        getLocaleFromGrid = true;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new InstantRenderer.
     * <p>
     * The renderer is configured to render with the given formatter, with the
     * empty string as its null representation.
     *
     * @param formatter the formatter to use, not {@code null}
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if formatter is null
     */
    public InstantRenderer ( DateTimeFormatter formatter )
    {
        this( formatter , "" );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new InstantRenderer.
     * <p>
     * The renderer is configured to render with the given formatter.
     *
     * @param formatter          the formatter to use, not {@code null}
     * @param nullRepresentation the textual representation of the {@code null} value
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if formatter is null
     */
    public InstantRenderer ( DateTimeFormatter formatter , String nullRepresentation )
    {
        super( Instant.class , nullRepresentation );

        if ( formatter == null )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "formatter may not be null" );
        }

        this.formatter = formatter;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new InstantRenderer.
     * <p>
     * The renderer is configured to render with the given string format, as
     * displayed in the grid's locale it is attached to, with an empty string as
     * its null representation.
     *
     * @param formatPattern the format pattern to format the date with, not {@code null}
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if format pattern is null
     * @see <a href=
     * "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns">
     * Format Pattern Syntax</a>
     */
    public InstantRenderer ( String formatPattern )
    {
        this( formatPattern , Locale.getDefault() );
        getLocaleFromGrid = true;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new InstantRenderer.
     * <p>
     * The renderer is configured to render with the given string format, as
     * displayed in the given locale, with an empty string as its null
     * representation.
     *
     * @param formatPattern the format pattern to format the date with, not {@code null}
     * @param locale        the locale to use, not {@code null}
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if format pattern is null
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if locale is null
     * @see <a href=
     * "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns">
     * Format Pattern Syntax</a>
     */
    public InstantRenderer ( String formatPattern , Locale locale )
    {
        this( formatPattern , locale , "" );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new InstantRenderer.
     * <p>
     * The renderer is configured to render with the given string format, as
     * displayed in the given locale.
     *
     * @param formatPattern      the format pattern to format the date with, not {@code null}
     * @param locale             the locale to use, not {@code null}
     * @param nullRepresentation the textual representation of the {@code null} value
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if format pattern is null
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if locale is null
     * @see <a href=
     * "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns">
     * Format Pattern Syntax</a>
     */
    public InstantRenderer ( String formatPattern , Locale locale , String nullRepresentation )
    {
        super( Instant.class , nullRepresentation );

        if ( formatPattern == null )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "format pattern may not be null" );
        }

        if ( locale == null )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "locale may not be null" );
        }

        formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( formatPattern , locale );
    }

    @Override
    public JsonValue encode ( Instant value )
    {
        String dateString;
        if ( value == null )
        {
            dateString = this.getNullRepresentation();
        } else if ( this.getLocaleFromGrid )
        {
            if ( null == this.getParentGrid() )
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Could not find a locale to format with: "
                                + "this renderer should either be attached to a grid "
                                + "or constructed with locale information" );
            }
            ZonedDateTime zdt = value.atZone( this.zoneId );  // Basil Bourque.
            Locale locale = this.getParentGrid().getLocale();
            dateString = zdt.format( formatter.withLocale( locale ) );
        } else
        {
            ZonedDateTime zdt = value.atZone( this.zoneId );  // Basil Bourque.
            dateString = zdt.format( formatter );
        }
        return encode( dateString , String.class );
    }

    @Override
    protected InstantRendererState getState ()
    {
        InstantRendererState s = ( InstantRendererState ) super.getState();
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    protected InstantRendererState getState ( boolean markAsDirty )
    {
        InstantRendererState s = ( InstantRendererState ) super.getState( markAsDirty );
        return s;
    }
}
```

### `InstantRendererConnector`

```
/*
 * By Basil Bourque. Taken almost entirely from source code published by Vaadin Ltd.
 *
 * --------
 *
 * Copyright 2000-2016 Vaadin Ltd.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 * use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
 * the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */
package com.basil.timepiece;

import com.vaadin.shared.ui.Connect;

/**
 * A connector for InstantRenderer.
 * <p>
 * The server-side Renderer operates on {@code Instant}s, but the data is
 * serialized as a string, and displayed as-is on the client side. This is to be
 * able to support the server's locale.
 *
 * @author Vaadin Ltd
 * @since 8.1
 */
@Connect( InstantRenderer.class )
public class InstantRendererConnector extends com.vaadin.client.connectors.grid.TextRendererConnector
{

    @Override
    public InstantRendererState getState ()
    {
        return ( InstantRendererState ) super.getState();
    }
}
```

### `InstantRendererState`

```
/*
 * By Basil Bourque. Taken almost entirely from source code published by Vaadin Ltd.
 *
 * --------
 *
 * Copyright 2000-2016 Vaadin Ltd.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 * use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
 * the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */
package com.basil.timepiece;

/**
 * Shared state of InstantRenderer.
 *
 * @author Vaadin Ltd
 * @since 8.1
 */
public class InstantRendererState extends com.vaadin.shared.ui.grid.renderers.TextRendererState
{
    // This code intentionally left blank.
}
```

## Source on BitBucket

I have posted my [complete Maven-driven project on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/basil_bourque/timecolumnrenderers), all the necessary files for column renderers for `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime`.

## Feature Request

I posted [Issue # 10208 *Implement column renderers for Vaadin Grid for other java.time types (Instant, OffsetDateTime, ZonedDateTime) to complement the LocalDate & LocalDateTime renderers in Vaadin 8.1.*](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/10208) on the Vaadin Framework GitHub page.

Comment: Have you tried with `?debug`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Special packaging required

Yes, special packaging is required. You cannot simply toss the [Vaadin Grid column renderer implementation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/clientsidewidgets/clientsidewidgets-grid.html) classes into a regular Vaadin app.

Two of the three classes needed for a column renderer implementation involve [client-side development](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/clientside/clientside-overview.html), rather than the usual [server-side development](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-overview.html) we do commonly in Vaadin app work.

Fortunately, this is easier than it might sound. To just do a simple column renderer, Vaadin fortunately provides some super-classes that do most of the heavy-lifting. So we need not learn about all the gory details of the [GWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) and [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) magic that goes on under the covers in Vaadin.

The path to success involves:

- Creating a separate project using a Vaadin-provided template to build your own [Vaadin Add-On](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/addons/addons-overview.html).
- Populating that project with source code taken from the [*Vaadin Framework* GitHub project](https://github.com/vaadin/framework).

### `vaadin-archetype-widget`

Start a new project using a [multi-module](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) [archetype](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/index.html) provided by the Vaadin team: `vaadin-archetype-widget` seen in [this list](https://vaadin.com/maven#archetypes).

[image: screen shot of IntelliJ > New Project > Create from archetype dialog box]

#### `addon` module

Once you have created a project from that archetype in your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), add your three column renderer classes as shown in this screen shot for an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) renderer.

- `Renderer` class goes in the 'addon' module’s main package.
- `RendererConnector` & `RendererState` class files go in the 'addon' module’s nested `client` package.

Of course, in real work you would delete the example `MyComponent…` files created by the archetype.

#### `demo` module

Once built you can try your column renderer in the 'demo' module’s Vaadin app by importing the package of the 'addon' module. In this case:

```
import org.basilbourque.timecolrenderers.InstantRenderer;
```

#### GitHub source

My successful implementation of a `Instant` column renderer was take entirely from three `LocalDateTimeRenderer` related classes provided with Vaadin 8.1.3 source code. You can find the current version of these classes by typing `LocalDateTimeRenderer` in the [GitHub find file feature](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/find/master).

[image]

- [`shared/src/main/java/com/vaadin/shared/ui/grid/renderers/LocalDateTimeRendererState.java`](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/shared/src/main/java/com/vaadin/shared/ui/grid/renderers/LocalDateTimeRendererState.java)
- [`server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/ui/renderers/LocalDateTimeRenderer.java`](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/ui/renderers/LocalDateTimeRenderer.java)
- [`client/src/main/java/com/vaadin/client/connectors/grid/LocalDateTimeRendererConnector.java`](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/client/src/main/java/com/vaadin/client/connectors/grid/LocalDateTimeRendererConnector.java)

[image: screen shot of 'Project' pane in IntelliJ showing the position of three Java source files within the package hierarchy]